# Python: module not found, immediately after installing it

Tags: python, pip

I'm working on Ubuntu 17.10

I've installed Python 3.6

I've installed the module named dedupe:

```
sudo pip install dedupe
...
Successfully installed...
...
sudo pip3 install dedupe
...
Requirement already satisfied...
...
```

But when I try to run something that uses it I get this error.

```
$ python dedupe_process.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dedupe_process.py", line 11, in <module>
    import dedupe
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dedupe'
```

It also doesn't work when I explicitly use `python3` to run it.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you start a Python shell, then run `import dedupe`, does that work?

Comment: Wait a minute, why did you install Python 3.6? It's already installed. How did you install it?

Comment: @wjandrea no that doesn't work. I get the same error. I installed Anaconda 3.6 from the web

Comment: Maybe try calling your script with the system Python binary, /usr/bin/python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also get the same error when i start using "kali linux" . Maybe your python3 is try to find your script's module in the "`/usr/local/lib/python3.x`" directory . So if that module is not there then the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dedupe'` error is happening .

Actually I don't have permanent solution, but you can try following one ..........

To solve that problem simpley go to that directory where the module is present to see the directory just run `sudo pip3 install "moduleName"` command on the "terminal"
you probably get something like this :-
 
                            "`Requirement already satisfied: 'moduleName' in /usr/local/lib/python3.x/dist-packages (moduleVersion)`"
                           or 
                            "`Requirement already satisfied: 'moduleName' in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (moduleVersion)`".

```
Then just copy that `Module` to the `/usr/local/lib/python3.` directory......
```

Hopefully it should work.......
  Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
pip install dedupe
```

Without 'sudo' command. Otherwise you'll install library without rw permissions for common user (only root can rw)